# How to install and setup SmokePing?

Tags: 10.10, networking, tools, ping

Any have good link to how to for SmokePing that is upto date for 10.10 or 10.04(aka mint11)?

Answer (score 2):

Here you can find detailed info [How to install and setup SmokePing](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man7/smokeping_install.7.html) on Ubuntu 10.10, 10.04, and for older versions as well. Hope it should cover your needs.